# Issue converting currency from string in before_validation callback

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm having an issue stripping dollar signs and commas out of a currency before validations are run. For some reason the value is being set to `0` when saved.

```
class Property < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_validation :format_currency

  validates :street_name_1, presence: true
  validates :city, presence: true
  validates :state, presence: true
  validates :postal_code, presence: true
  validates :rate, presence: true, numericality: true

  private
  def format_currency
    self.rate = rate.to_s.gsub(/[^0-9\.]/, '').to_i # Strip out non-numeric characters
  end

end
```

When I do `'$3,500'.to_s.gsub(/[^0-9\.]/, '').to_i` in the rails console it correctly returns "3500". `rate` is being passed in to the model properly from the form as well.

For the life of me I can't figure out why it's not properly setting the value on save. Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: I needed to override the default setter and do my gsub when the rate is set due to the database column being integer.

```
def rate=(rate)
    write_attribute(:rate, rate.to_s.gsub(/[^0-9\.]/, '').to_i)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are storing the `rate` column as an integer, and you are using Rails, I propose that your remove the `format_currency` method entirely. Rails has a method to deal with currencies already: [`number_to_currency`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/NumberHelper/number_to_currency).

When you want to output the price, simple use the helper:

```
number_to_currency @property.rate
```

This gives you greater flexibility too, since you can localise it and pass it a number of other options. [Have a look at the API](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/NumberHelper/number_to_currency).

Edit, as per OP editing the question:

If you want to save something in that format, why don't you apply the dollar sine in the model?

```
before_save :set_rate
def set_rate
  self.rate = "$#{rate}"
end
```

Comment: I'm actually trying to save something in the format ($3,500) to the database. Not the other way around. I figured it out and updated my question with the answer.

Comment: @user3197108 See my update. But why not just add the `$` before saving the `rate` column? Why bother with the regexp complexity?

Comment: I don't think you're understanding me correctly. A user would enter something like "$3,500" in the form which would then be passed to the model. The model has a "rate" column that is an integer. I cannot store $ or , in an integer column. I just need the raw integer.